# C# WndProc event handler

Tags: c#, controls, wndproc

I added a form control to my form in a designer. But I need to override that control's WndProc. Can I do that without creating a new control extending the old one? Because when I extend the old one like this my designer won't work anymore:

```
partial class ThatControlWithWndProc : TheControlIActuallyWant {}
```

Or how can I get my designer to work with this new control that I created and not throw me an error?

Comment: i am very much sure that, designer still remains the same, as that control is still a subclass of `System.Windows.Form.Control`

Answer (score 0):

If you just edit the `.Designer.cs` file directly to refer to your overridden control, and ensure that it follows the rules for controls to be designer-compatible (like having a default constructor, and not relying on any other initialisation) you should be fine.

Comment: What is the default constructor supposed to be like? I added an empty one "ThatControlWithWndProc() {}" and designer still throws me an error "either undeclared or was never assigned".

Comment: If you add a default constructor, it needs to call `InitializeComponent();`  (Having said that, you don't strictly need one as long as one of the base classes has one.)  If you continue to get errors, please post the entire message and a stack trace if you have one.